# JQUERY - Change hidden input with multiple submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I Have a simple FORM with a Hidden Input only - and multiple submit buttons (1 to infinite)

When the user click on submit - the button change the hidden input value to submit the form.

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer">
    <input type="submit" value="A">
    <input type="submit" value="B">
    <input type="submit" value="C">
</form>
```

```
$("#form").on("submit", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var currentForm = $(this);
   $("#answer").val() = $("#submit").val();
});
```

how can I do this?

I'm trying Jquery, but - something is wrong. I know this is easy, but I'm not an expert

tks a lot!
Daniel

Comment: Show what you tried....

Comment: @epascarello uptdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I know what you mean...
For example, this is HTML of your form

```
<form action="" id="form_id_example">
    <input type="hidden" name="change_value" id="change_value">
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

The jQuery is something similar to that

```
$("#form_id_example").on("submit", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var currentForm = $(this);
   $("#change_value").val("new input value");
   $("#form_id_example").off("submit");
   currentForm.submit();
});
```